# System of equations with a unique solution, no solution or an infinite number of solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I was doing a past OCR Further Pure 1 Paper from January 2011, but came across the following question that I could not solve, even with the help of the mark scheme:

> Determine whether the simultaneous equations
> $$6x - 6y + z = 3k$$
> $$3x + 6y + z = 0$$
> $$4x + 2y + z = k$$
>
> where $k$ is a non-zero constant, have a unique solution, no solution or an infinite number of solutions, justifying your answer.

Can anyone help me with the question?

Comment: Does your third equation have a typo, or is there indeed no $z$ term in it?

Comment: @RandomUser Sorry, it was indeed a typo

Comment: Are you familiar with the various techniques for solving systems of linear equations? http://www.purplemath.com/modules/systlin4.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming here that the last equation should be $4x + 2y + z = k$.

We can solve this system using linear algebra.  To do this, note that the system is equivalent to the matrix equation 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix} 6 & -6 & 1  \\
  3 & 6 & 1  \\
4 & 2 & 1  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}3k\\0\\k\end{pmatrix}. \end{equation*}

Now use [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) on the augmented matrix (I've skipped the details of how to do this):
\begin{equation*}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 6 & -6 & 1 & 3k \\
  3 & 6 & 1 & 0 \\
4 & 2 & 1 & k \end{array}\right) \to \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & 0 & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{k}{3}\\  0 & 1 & \frac{1}{18} & \frac{-k}{6} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)\end{equation*}

This matrix is equivalent to the system

\begin{eqnarray*}
x +\frac{2}{9}z&=& \frac{k}{3} \\
y + \frac{1}{18}z &=& \frac{-k}{6}\end{eqnarray*}
Now we see that given any value of $z$, we find a solution by setting
\begin{eqnarray*}
x &=& \frac{k}{3} - \frac{2}{9}z\\
y &=& \frac{-k}{6} - \frac{1}{18}z
\end{eqnarray*}

Therefore, for any $k$, the system has infinitely many solutions.  The solution set is a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$, with parametrization
\begin{equation*}
\left(\frac{k}{3},\frac{-k}{6}, 0\right) + t\left(\frac{-2}{9}, \frac{-1}{18}, 1\right).\end{equation*}

Comment: I think you've made an error. Note that the determinant of the matrix is zero, so the system is degenerate. There is another solution: $(k/3,-k/6,0)$, and another: $(0,-k/4,3k/2)$. In fact, I believe the entire plane containing your solution and these 2 other points solves the system.

Comment: Rick, thanks for the correction.  All three solutions are collinear, so the solution space is a line.  As the matrix is clearly not rank 1, we see that the nullspace, and hence the solution space, can't be dimension 2.

Comment: Right. I was doing all the calculations in my head, so I didn't notice the rank when I wrote the comment. +1 for the corrected answer.